# Symfony : I get a 500 instead of a 404

Tags: symfony1, http-status-code-404

I've created custom 404 error pages for my symfony application, but they don't seem to work. In dev I see :

```
This request has been forwarded to a 404 error page by the action "blabla".
```

But in prod, the page is just blank; I get a 500 error.

In the logs, the error is :

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in /var/www/myproject/apps/myapp/modules/default/actions/actions.class.php on line 7
```

*default/actions/actions.class.php* is the following :

```
<?php
/**
 * Error page for page not found (404) error
 *
 */

public function executeError404()
{

}

public function executeSecure()
{

}
?>
```

I followed [this tutorial on symfony-check.org](http://symfony-check.org/permalink/customize-the-oops-page-not-found-page)

Comment: If I remove the "public" keywords, I get : `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'sfError404Exception' with message 'Action "default/error404" does not exist.'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer all by myself :D
I'd forgotten part of the file :

```
class defaultActions extends sfActions
{
    public function executeError404() {}
}
```